# Why Does My App Component Render an App Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Experienced Angular 1 developer trying to learn Angular 2. I have a barebones application that is behaving strangely. I'm using MeteorJS to serve up everything. Here is the application structure-

```
client/
    components/
        articles/
            articles.component.html
            articles.component.ts
    index.html
    app.html
    app.ts
```

index.html -

```
<template>
  <app></app>
</template>
```

app.html -

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['Articles']">Articles</a>
      </li>
      <li>Nav 2</li>
      <li>Nav 3</li>
      <li>Nav 4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </section>
</template>
```

app.ts -

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2-meteor';

module WSN.App {

  @Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
  })

  export class AppComponent {

  }

  bootstrap(AppComponent);
}
```

And I won't show the articles files unless that's requested. What I get with this is this html-

```
<body>
  <app>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <app></app>
      </body>
    </html>
  </app>
</body>
```

Changing `templateUrl` to `template` has the same issue. Anyone have any ideas why `app.html` isn't loading? And why the html is doubling up? No errors in the console.

Edit:

Updated the AppComponent constructor to -

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
      alert('x');
    }
  }
```

And I am seeing the alert.

Comment: Why do you wrap `<app></app>` in `index.html` and the content of the AppComponents template with a `<template>` tag?

Comment: Dunno. Figured there needed to be a root element.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was I wasn't referencing the path from the web root.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
  })
```

Should've been-

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'client/app.html'
  })
```

I wish there were some error thrown. Also, why would it print everything twice?